# script.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript

i have been walking through this problem of script.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') how can i solve this ?

`

```
masterPlay.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime<=0){
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-play-circle');
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-pause-circle');
        gif.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    else{
        audioElement.pause();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-play-circle');
        gif.style.opacity = 0;
    }
})
```

I don't know how to solve it ca any body help me out?

Comment: Moving `<script src="..."></script> after <body/>` tag might solve issue. script loading before body so event is `null`

Comment: or check if masterPlay is not null then run code `if(masterPlay) {...code}`

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: The current best practice is to include your JavaScript code as a [module](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) using `<script type="module" src="path/to/code.mjs"></script>` which solves this problem and many more.

Answer (score 0):

its means masterPlay property is null! you shoud check masterPlay.
your informations is not enough